# Custom maven plugin - what are the default parameters?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom maven plugin, and want to get some information about the project.

After some searching around, I found that I can set parameters to certain project related values (presumably from the POM?) - e.g.

```
/**
 * @goal myPlugin
 */
public class MyTestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  /**
   * @parameter expression="${project}"
   * @required
   * @read-only
   */
  private Object project;

  @Override
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    getLog().info(project.toString());
  }
}
```

However, I cannot find any documentation on what parameters are available in this format. At the moment, I'm proceeding with trial and error, but that's proving a bit frustrating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [short list](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) of available properties. You may also want to look trough available Maven [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) [tutorials](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html).

Answer (score 2):

See the [Mojo API specification, section The Descriptor and Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html).

There is a good introduction to writing plugins in [Maven: The Complete Reference: 11.4 Writing a Custom Plugin, section 11.4.5. Mojo Class Annotations](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html) on the Sonatype website.

Comment: The link to the book does not work. This seems to be the new link: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html